# Angular JS - Sharing controller between directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-directive

Can't seem to figure out why this is not working...

**What I'm trying to do:**

I need to be able to share the controller from the mainContent directive with the directive for focus and I keep getting this error: `Cannot set property 'element' of undefined`.

I'm practically copying/pasting from this example : https://www.codeschool.com/screencasts/egghead-io-flexible-angular-directives : so I'm not sure why it isn't working?

**Relevant Code:**

```
//html
<mainContent id="mainContent">
  <focus>whatever</focus>
</mainContent>

//js
angular.module('home', [])
  .directive('mainContent', mainContent)
  .directive('focus', focus);

mainContent.$inject = [];
function mainContent() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.element = '';
    }
  }
}

focus.$inject = [];
function focus() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div id="focus"><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    require: '^?mainContent', // also tried 'mainContent' && '^mainContent'
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.element = 'such wow';
    }
  };
}
```

(yes, I know this syntax isn't as common however it follows the style guides for my project)
Thanks in advance, any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @PSL just edited it.

Comment: Typo it should be `<main-content id="mainContent">
  <focus>whatever</focus>
</main-content>`

Comment: omg... I'm kicking myself right now. I already knew about the naming conventions and somehow I still missed it haha. Errors gone now. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: There is a possibility that your answer might get closed for being typo.. So probably you can remove it or post an answer yourself and accept it when time permits.. Cheers!! One more thing since your have the `require: '^?mainContent',` as an optional requirement, it is better to have a null check.